# flex accessing children of a list component

Tags: apache-flex

when I try to loop through the children of a List component that has buttons in it, I can't seem to access those children.

I try

```
for(var btnNum:Number = 0; btnNum < myList.numChildren; btnNum++)
{

  trace(myList.getChildAt(btnNum);

}
```

but it is giving some other instance, not the button instances.

and the weeklist

```
<mx:List id="myList"  dataProvider="{_data.mappoints.week.@number}"  >
                <mx:itemRenderer  >
                    <mx:Component>


                        <mx:Button buttonMode="true" toggle="true"  alpha="1" width="116" height="35" label="WEEK {data}" >

                        </mx:Button>

                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:List>
```

Comment: pfunc, do you mind posting the actual answer? the answer you've selected doesn't really explain the solution.

Comment: This was 2 years ago and I have since moved on from Flex and that project. I think I just kept digging down in the list until I found the buttons and there wasn't an easy answer that I found at the time.  Sorry, that's the best I can do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list isn't full of buttons, it's full of components.

Do a `trace(ObjectUtil.toString(myList);` and you will get a good output of what your list really is and how to get to the buttons.

Comment: I got to the buttons, it was pretty tedious. Seems like there should be an easier way. But I got it.

Comment: Creating a dictionary object and storing a reference to your buttons there might make accessing them easier.